# Unable to download full html using Wget in batch script

Tags: html, batch-file, wget

I'm creating a database from digikey parts and using Wget in my batch script to retrieve the html. I'm unable to download the full html using a URL via keywords.

As an example, I'm able to download the the html into my "Test_Read_File.txt" using the URL "https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/DF3-5P-2DSA-01/H3924-ND/560482" but unable if I use the URL "https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=DF3-5P-2DSA(01)". Both URLs will open the same page. I would use the first URL but am unable too because of the "560482" number at the end which changes for every component. My main program will call a .txt file with thousands of manufacturer part numbers and insert them one by one as a replacement for DF3-5P-2DSA(01). I don't think Agent is necessary in this case.

```
SET AGENT="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"

Wget -U %AGENT% -O Test_Read_File.txt "https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=DF3-5P-2DSA(01)"
```

Comment: I got a 403 (forbidden) when trying to reach `https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=DF3-5P-2DSA(01)` -- you sure it doesn't require some auth (headers)?

Comment: In my case I need to begin with passing by a proxy by using: SET http_proxy=http://-------:---. So that could be the difference. The URL works for me but only downloads a small html file not containing the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a python script (.py) that used selenium and created a call from my batch.

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=EDH106M016A9BAA')

sleep(3)
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

saveFile = open('FILE-LOCATION','w',encoding='utf-8')
saveFile.write(str(soup))
saveFile.close()
driver.quit()
```